# New operator taking memory from already allocated Buffer Pool

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, new-operator

I have added a new class and created its object using `new`.

I saw the program crashed due to this. On further debugging, I found that there is an existing class which is allocated using placement new from a Buffer Pool.

So chances are my `new` operator is unaware of this and getting memory allocated from that buffer?

How can I confirm this and how can I avoid this problem to not allocate from that pool?

Snippet of the code:
My code is called before the pool is allocated.

Where the Pool is used

```
// Initialize buffer pool for path pbject buffers

    UINT32 size = CHOP_MAX_PATH_NUM * sizeof(Buffer<pathElement>);

/* Create the path manager for each channelized sonet line */

    for (UINT8 lineId = 0; lineId < maxLines; lineId++) {
       /* Get the max STS Paths for this line */
       chanSonetLineMgr[lineId] =
          new ChopOC48SonetPathMgr(
              bay, lineId, &pathElementPool,
              NULL, dynamic_cast<SonetLineNg *>(linesNg[lineId]),
              NULL, //Alert: When Chop Path Mgr is ready
```

Comment: This can not happen, the OS will not give you the memory allocated for the buffer pool until you release it.

Comment: The question is of course, is the buffer pool already allocated with `new`?

Comment: The code is pretty huge, spans across multiple files. I will paste the  relevant code. The coonstructor for the pool is called later, so that means its cannot allocate from the pool ?